# Weird trackpad & keyboard issue with MacBook Pro E2015

Tags: keyboard, macos, sleep-wake, trackpad

I've had some issues with my trackpad and keyboard on my MacBook Pro 13 (Early 2015) for the past 3-4 weeks. After being awaken from sleep mode, they were sometimes unresponsive. At first, a couple of hard reboots made them work again, but lately no number of reboots fix it. However, they usually come back to life again by themselves after some time (12-24 hours).

At wake up, when the trackpad and keyboard stops working, I found this error message in the system's log:

```
5/9/16 22:44:49.000 kernel[0]: Error: AppleHSSPIController::doSPITransfer NAK received from device
5/9/16 22:44:49.000 kernel[0]: Error: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad::IssueMessage Failed to issue message the bus error: 0xe00002eb
5/9/16 22:44:49.000 kernel[0]: Error: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad::setPowerState AppleHSSPIDevice : Resume Device in Power On failed with error 0xe00002eb
```

Some other findings:

- The keys can sometimes wake the computer, but as soon as it wakes up they don't work.
- They don't work at boot (i.e., cmd+R, cmd+V etc do not work).
- I've reinstalled Mac OS (using net recovery, cmd+opt+R). I've also reset the SMC and PRAM.
- When they don't work, there's no sign of neither the keyboard nor trackpad in either the "SPI" or "USB" tabs in the "System Information".
- Disconnecting Bluetooth and USB devices do not help.
- The problem is uncorrelated with how warm the computer is (i.e., it's not an expanding battery problem).
- The power key on the keyboard works fine.
- External keyboards and trackpads work fine.

Surely, this all sounds like a hardware problem. However, here's the weird part. **When I boot up Ubuntu from an USB stick, the keyboard and trackpad work perfectly.** Rebooting into Mac OS, they're still dead however. I have a hard time imagining that this is a hardware problem for that reason.

Any ideas what could be the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: If someone stumble in here with the same problem: after a lot of back and forth, I handed in my MacBook to Apple. They replaced the trackpad cable and now it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now on a Macbookpro12,1 (works in Ubuntu, doesn't work in Mac OS), but for quite a while, my macbook has required a PRAM reset (these days, even that requires an external keyboard. SMC reset works on the internal keyboard though) on every boot to be able to input anything at all without a ~40 second delay. Did you have that as well?

Comment: @hyperair No, that doesn't sound familiar. It could happen that the keyboard had a slight delay just before it died. But other than that, if it worked, it worked perfectly. As I said, in the end, I sent it in for repair, and that fixed it. A couple of month later, the same problem popped up, and went for repair directly then.

Comment: Wait, so the problem keeps reoccurring?

Comment: I have the same problem on the Macbookpro12,1 with intermittent loss of SPI communication with the kbd/touchpad. I'm certain it's due to glitching cables. I think it's just luck if it works again after a reboot or not and magic  pram resets etc, if it's a faulty cable it needs to be fixed.

Comment: A slightly late update: The keyboard and trackpad completely stopped working for me sometime last year, and I had to send it back for repair twice (first time, they said they replaced the keyboard cable, but it still didn't work after it came back). Second time, I've no idea what they did to fix it, but I'm guessing they had to replace some board somewhere. It's still working til today.